# Nested collections with Backbone.Marionette

Tags: backbone.js, marionette

I want to create a calendar which is a day collection, and every day is a collection of appointments. The structure of day object is:

```
day:{
    date:'08-06-2012',
    appointment: {
        time_begin:'12:55',
        time_end: '16:40',
        customer: 'Jaime'
    }
}
```

At this moment i have this models and views:

```
// CALENDAR COLLECTION
App.Calendar.Collection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    // MODEL
    model: App.Day.Model
}
```

When calendar collection fetch data form the server, it gets complete day objects including appointments.

```
// CALENDAR VIEW
App.Calendar.View = Backbone.Marionette.CompositeView.extend({
    // TEMPLATE
    template: Handlebars.compile(templates.find('#calendar-template').html()),
    // ITEM VIEW
    itemView: App.Day.View,
    // ITEM VIEW CONTAINER
    itemViewContainer: '#calendar-collection-block'
});

// DAY MODEL
App.Day.Model = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    // PARSE
    parse:function(data){
        console.log(data);
        return data;
    }
});

// DAY VIEW
App.Day.View = Backbone.Marionette.CompositeView.extend({
    collection: App.Day.Model,
    itemView: App.CalendarAppointment.View, //---->I NEED TO DEFINE THIS, NOT SURE HOW
    template: Handlebars.compile(templates.find('#day-template').html())
});
```

The day model needs to be a collection of appointments and shouldn't be necessary to fetch data from the server because it's inside every day.

How can i do this?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

if I understand the question right, you're asking how to get the data from your `Day` model, `Appointment` collection, in to the `CalendarApointmentView` itemView?

Your `Day.View` can be set up to populate the `collection` of this composite view, which will then be pushed in to the item views:

```
// DAY VIEW
App.Day.View = Backbone.Marionette.CompositeView.extend({
    collection: App.Day.Model,
    itemView: App.CalendarAppointment.View,
    template: Handlebars.compile(templates.find('#day-template').html()),

    initialize: function(){

      // since `this.model` is a `Day` model, it has the data you need
      this.collection = this.model.get("CalendarAppointments");

    }
});
```

One thing to note: the `this.collection` must be a valid Backbone.Collection. If your model stores the appointment data as a simple array, then you need to do this:

```
var appointments = this.model.get("CalendarAppointments");
this.collection = new AppointmentCollection(appointments);
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: @Derick, for deeply nested collections can a compositeView.itemView point to another compositeView? Is there a limit on how deep you can nest them?

Answer (score 2):

This looks like the perfect usecase for [backbone-relational](https://github.com/PaulUithol/Backbone-relational), which would automatically take care of parsing your nested data and creating the nested collection structure.

Comment: was the question was more around how to structure the views?